# How to Store MySQL Trigger exception / failure info into Table or in Variables

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I am stuck at somewhere and I need some help from you.

## Scenario

I have two databases i.e., `test_db1` and `test_db2` and have `users` table on both of them. Both databases initially are empty (0 rows).

Here's `users` table schema:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `age` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

After that, I have written some triggers for `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` events on `test_db1.users` table, Below is what each trigger does:

- on `INSERT` in `test_db1.users`, insert same row in `test_db2.users`
- on `UPDATE` in `test_db1.users`, update same row in `test_db2.users`
- on `DELETE` in `test_db1.users`, delete same row from `test_db2.users`

And here's the trigger code snippet.

```
DELIMITER //

-- TRIGGER FOR INSERT
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `test_db1_users_bi`;
CREATE TRIGGER `test_db1_users_bi` BEFORE INSERT ON `users` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `test_db2`.`users` (id, name, age) VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.name, NEW.age);
END; //

-- TRIGGER FOR UPDATE
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `test_db1_users_bu`;
CREATE TRIGGER `test_db1_users_bu` BEFORE UPDATE ON `users` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    UPDATE `test_db2`.`users`
        SET name = NEW.name,
            age = NEW.age
        WHERE id = NEW.id;
END; //

-- TRIGGER FOR DELETE
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `test_db1_users_bd`;
CREATE TRIGGER `test_db1_users_bd` BEFORE DELETE ON `users` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM `test_db2`.`users`
        WHERE id = OLD.id;
END; //

-- DELIMITER;
```

Now, the Question!

Currently, this doesn't have any errors/exceptions handlers defined in triggers.. So, I want to handle that too but I don't know how to do that. I just don't know how would I get the exception and it's properties like exceptions - error code, error message?

I just want to store the caught exception/error into `test_db1`.`errors` table from each of the trigger (if fails):

Here's `errors` table schema something looks like:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `errors`;
CREATE TABLE `errors` (
  `id` int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `error_code` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `error_message` TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `emailed` TINYINT DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

FYI: Below are the possible failures:

- If `test_db2` is not there or unable to connect?
- If `INSERT` trigger fails i.e., whatever the reason?
- If `UPDATE` trigger fails i.e., whatever the reason?
- If `DELETE` trigger fails i.e., whatever the reason?

If anyone can Just let me know how can I get the exception and it's properties like error code, error message and store it to variables from inside triggers so that then I will perform insert to store them into table?

I am running MySQL version: 5.5+

Thanks!

Comment: Check [14.6.7 Condition Handling](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/condition-handling.html).

Comment: not getting.. just tried with examples given on documentation but seems it's not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a hack via `DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER` and `GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION`, so just thought, I must share it here.

Here's my complete final script which keeps backup (sync) for both databases `users` table what it means is that any update on `test_db1` (which we may call it as a productionDB) will occur on `test_db2` (which we may call it to as stagingDB):

```
/*
Create two databases:
    1. `test_db1`
    2. `test_db2`
and execute below create *Table script* on both databases.
after that execute *Triggers Script* on `test_db1` only..
*/

/*
    TABLE STRUCTURE FOR `users`
*/

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `age` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

/*
    TABLE STRUCTURE FOR `errors`
*/

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `errors`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `errors` (
  `id` int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `message` TEXT NOT NULL,
  `query_type` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `record_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `on_db` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `on_table` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `emailed` TINYINT DEFAULT 0,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

/*
    TRIGGERS SCRIPTS FOR INSERT, UPDATE AND DELETE OPERATIONS
*/

DELIMITER //

-- TRIGGER FOR INSERT
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `test_db1_users_ai`;
CREATE TRIGGER `test_db1_users_ai` AFTER INSERT ON `users` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    -- Declare variables to hold diagnostics area information
    DECLARE errorCode CHAR(5) DEFAULT '00000';
    DECLARE errorMessage TEXT DEFAULT '';

    -- Declare exception handler for failed insert
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
    BEGIN
      GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1
        errorCode = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, errorMessage = MESSAGE_TEXT;
    END;

    -- Perform the insert
    INSERT INTO `test_db2`.`users` (id, name, age) VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.name, NEW.age);

    -- Check whether the insert was successful
    IF errorCode != '00000' THEN
        INSERT INTO `errors` (code, message, query_type, record_id, on_db, on_table) VALUES (errorCode, errorMessage, 'insert', NEW.id, 'test_db2', 'users');
    END IF;
END; //

-- TRIGGER FOR UPDATE
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `test_db1_users_au`;
CREATE TRIGGER `test_db1_users_au` AFTER UPDATE ON `users` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    -- Declare variables to hold diagnostics area information
    DECLARE errorCode CHAR(5) DEFAULT '00000';
    DECLARE errorMessage TEXT DEFAULT '';

    -- Declare exception handler for failed insert
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
    BEGIN
      GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1
        errorCode = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, errorMessage = MESSAGE_TEXT;
    END;

    -- Perform the update
    UPDATE `test_db2`.`users`
        SET name = NEW.name,
            age = NEW.age
        WHERE id = NEW.id;

    -- Check whether the update was successful
    IF errorCode != '00000' THEN
        INSERT INTO `errors` (code, message, query_type, record_id, on_db, on_table) VALUES (errorCode, errorMessage, 'update', NEW.id, 'test_db2', 'users');
    END IF;
END; //

-- TRIGGER FOR DELETE
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `test_db1_users_ad`;
CREATE TRIGGER `test_db1_users_ad` AFTER DELETE ON `users` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    -- Declare variables to hold diagnostics area information
    DECLARE errorCode CHAR(5) DEFAULT '00000';
    DECLARE errorMessage TEXT DEFAULT '';

    -- Declare exception handler for failed insert
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
    BEGIN
      GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1
        errorCode = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, errorMessage = MESSAGE_TEXT;
    END;

    -- Perform the delete
    DELETE FROM `test_db2`.`users`
        WHERE id = OLD.id;

    -- Check whether the insert was successful
    IF errorCode != '00000' THEN
        INSERT INTO `errors` (code, message, query_type, record_id, on_db, on_table) VALUES (errorCode, errorMessage, 'delete', OLD.id, 'test_db2', 'users');
    END IF;
END; //

-- DELIMITER;
```

Hope this will help others when they come over here.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

Check out the syntax for DECLARE HANDLER

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/declare-handler.html

Also, if you're trying to debug a SP, this might be helpful for you:

http://www.bluegecko.net/mysql/debugging-stored-procedures/

Upon trigger you can use something like below :

```
    CREATE TRIGGER `my_table_AINS` AFTER INSERT ON `my_table` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
        RESIGNAL;
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLWARNING
        RESIGNAL;
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
        RESIGNAL; 
    -- Do the work of the trigger.
END
```

Hope this may help you.

Comment: what does that RESIGNAL do? I want to store the exception/warning/error code and message into a table.. ?

Comment: not getting.. just tried with examples given on documentation but seems it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like Master and Slave server/DB scenario. You can look into **Binary Logging**. So, any manipulation in Master server will be recorded as an event and same gets applied to slave server.
[Checkout MySQL official reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-logging.html)