# MySQL How to check if query successfully executed?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 queries:

```
1. INSERT, 2. UPDATE and 3. DELETE
```

I want to know is there anyway so that i can check directly (i.e., without run another query for check) if query is executed successfully or not? if it doesn't (i.e., returned some error/exception) then I want to save that error/exception into some variables?

For Example, Below are my queries:

`INSERT` Query:

```
INSERT INTO `users` (id, name, age) VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.name, NEW.age);
```

`UPDATE` Query:

```
UPDATE `test_db2`.`users`
        SET name = NEW.name,
            age = NEW.age
        WHERE id = NEW.id;
```

`DELETE` Query:

```
DELETE FROM `test_db2`.`users`
        WHERE id = OLD.id;
```

Thanks.

Here's the simple INSERT trigger using Handler (I tried):

```
DELIMITER //

-- TRIGGER FOR INSERT
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `test_db1_users_ai`;
CREATE TRIGGER `test_db1_users_ai` AFTER INSERT ON `users` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    -- Perform the insert
    INSERT INTO `test_db2`.`users` (id, name, age) VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.name, NEW.age);
    -- Handler if this ^ above INSERT fails. 
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
        GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 @sqlstate = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, @errno = MYSQL_ERRNO, @text = MESSAGE_TEXT;
        --SET @full_error = CONCAT("ERROR ", @errno, " (", @sqlstate, "): ", @text);
        INSERT INTO `test_db1`.`errors` (error_code, error_message) VALUES (@errno, @text);
        --SELECT @full_error;
    END;
END; //
```

Comment: you can generate success_flag or status or count after each your operation and on the another hand you can store error/messages in log table ..That will convey your operation record :)

Comment: Hi Jordan, Though, I don't want to run another operation/query to count/etc. Also, Or If I do then how can I get what error code and message was occured on failure?

Comment: BTW, I want to insert the error `(code, message)` into my `errors` table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37853801/5228251

> Check this out below (i.e., Copied from above source):

```
-- TRIGGER FOR INSERT
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `test_db1_users_ai`;
CREATE TRIGGER `test_db1_users_ai` AFTER INSERT ON `users` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    -- Declare variables to hold diagnostics area information
    DECLARE errorCode CHAR(5) DEFAULT '00000';
    DECLARE errorMessage TEXT DEFAULT '';

    -- Declare exception handler for failed insert
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
    BEGIN
      GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1
        errorCode = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, errorMessage = MESSAGE_TEXT;
    END;

    -- Perform the insert
    INSERT INTO `test_db2`.`users` (id, name, age) VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.name, NEW.age);

    -- Check whether the insert was successful
    IF errorCode != '00000' THEN
        INSERT INTO `errors` (code, message, query_type, record_id, on_db, on_table) VALUES (errorCode, errorMessage, 'insert', NEW.id, 'test_db2', 'users');
    END IF;
END; //
```

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL you can declare [error / warning handlers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare-handler.html) that can capture various errors and warnings. If you combine a handler with [get diagnostics command](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/get-diagnostics.html), then you can capture even the exact error / warning in a general handler as well.

I found the following blog post on [Improve your Stored Procedure Error Handling with GET DIAGNOSTICS](http://www.chriscalender.com/improve-your-stored-procedure-error-handling-with-get-diagnostics/) that summarises how to capture the error message in stored programs within MySQL:

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
BEGIN
    GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 @sqlstate = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, @errno = MYSQL_ERRNO, @text = MESSAGE_TEXT;
    SET @full_error = CONCAT("ERROR ", @errno, " (", @sqlstate, "): ", @text);
    SELECT @full_error;
END;
```

Obviously, you can log the error in @full_error in a table, if required. If no error handlers kick in, then the sql statement successfully ran.

With inserts and updates you can also use the [row_count()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count) function to determine the number of records affected. If this number is 0, that could be an indication of an error.

Comment: I have placed this in my trigger after the query line but seems it doesn't work on failure.

Comment: Since I'm a really experienced mind reader, I can tell you that you made a mistake in the 42nd line of the trigger.

Comment: i don't get it. what does that mean i.e., 42nd line of the trigger?

Comment: You have made a certain change to a certain code of yours. You have not shared the change and final code, but you expect me to tell you what's wrong with it. Well, that would require mind reading capabilities.

Comment: Oh, yeah!! I have added at the last of question description.

Comment: Then pls read the documentation on handlers, do not just randomly insert the handler into your code. The 1st link of my answer points you to this documentation.