# How to properly execute an exception handler in mysql to collect error data?

Tags: mysql, sql, exception, stored-procedures

I am attempting to collect error data from queries in mysql via stored procedures and am unable to get the following to work. Wondering where I am going wrong. I am using this previous question as my guide:

[How to Store MySQL Trigger exception / failure info into Table or in Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37680461/how-to-store-mysql-trigger-exception-failure-info-into-table-or-in-variables)

My code below should throw an error that is logged in my error table but it doesn't seem to log any errors. Where am i going wrong?

**My Code:**

```
-- error table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS platenet.errors (
     code varchar(30) NOT NULL,
     message TEXT NOT NULL,
     query_type varchar(50) NOT NULL,
     record_id int(11) NOT NULL,
     on_db varchar(50) NOT NULL,
     on_table varchar(50) NOT NULL
);

-- tbl1
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS platenet.tblOne (
    name varchar(100),
    id INT(3)
);

-- my stored procedure
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS platenet.my_procedure;
CREATE PROCEDURE platenet.my_procedure()
BEGIN
    -- Declare variables to hold diagnostics area information
    DECLARE errorCode CHAR(5) DEFAULT '00000';
    DECLARE errorMessage TEXT DEFAULT '';
    -- Declare exception handler for failed insert
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
    BEGIN
      GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1
        errorCode = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, errorMessage = MESSAGE_TEXT;
    END;
    -- Perform the insert
    INSERT INTO platenet.tblOne VALUES('James', 'one.4');

    -- Check whether the insert was successful
    IF errorCode != '00000' THEN
        INSERT INTO `errors` (code, message, query_type, record_id, on_db, on_table) VALUES (errorCode, errorMessage, 'insert', NEW.id, 'test_db2', 'users');
    END IF;
END; $$

-- call my procedure
CALL platenet.my_procedure();

-- error table should have one error logged
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM platenet.errors;
```

Comment: Unless you have strict sql mode enabled, mysql will silently convert 'one.4' into 0 and issues an incorrect value warning. Drop your stored proc, enable strict sql mode, recreate your stored proc and then execute it.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't change anything. Also when I run the query `INSERT INTO platenet.tblOne VALUES('James', 'one.4');` individually it still calls an error, so the stored procedure should be treating this the same. Enabling strict mode definitely stops the value from inserting into `tblOne` but it does not insert error data into the `errors` table.

Comment: The sqlstate for this error is HY000, which means general error. Not sure if this type of error is classed as sql exception. The mysql documentation is not particularly clear on this. The hadler man page suggests yes, but the error message components page suggests no. Try it with an error which sqlstate is not HY000.